# can I use buttons instead of text in showing suggestion in autocomplete

Tags: android, button, autocomplete, textview, multiautocompletetextview

I know that autocomplete uses text element to show the suggestions
I want to make the suggestions appeared as buttons instead of the dropdown menu

how can I implement the onclick method to affect the auto suggestion ?

Comment: you have to make a custom listview using adapters, that would help.

Comment: @Saad custome list view and put the buttons inside that list ?